# Exporting PHP output into Microsoft Excel

Tags: php, excel, transfer

I am trying to convert the contents of table named "Update2" in PHP page.

this is the converter:

```
header("Content-type: application");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfilename.xls");
```

and this is the code fraction:

```
<?php
$output_sql="select * from update2 where update_com_ag=1 order by update_fullname ASC";
$output_query=mysql_query($output_sql,$con);
while($output=mysql_fetch_array($output_query)){?>
<tr>
    <td valign="top"><?php echo strtoupper($output['telephone_number']);?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
```

However, let say the telephone number is 1601000021056, the output in excel file will be 1.601E+12. Is there any solutions to solve this problem? I've tried several methods, but still not working.

Thanks guys!!

Comment: Why don't you seperate the area code from the phone number by a space?

Answer (score 0):

Go to excel, highlight the column for phone numbers. Right click and go to Format Cells. Go to Number tab. Then on the left, you can choose a different format. Like Number with 0 decimal places might do it.

Answer (score 0):

Excel program is displaying in that format because of space restrictions. Increase the column width and it will show the number correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In excel, if you prepend a value with a single quote it will treat that value as string, even if it is a number. Not sure if it works with your export method, but it's worth a try.

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top">'<?php echo strtoupper($output['telephone_number']);?></td>
</tr>
```